# Did Andy know all along?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-old-guard

In the Netflix movie - The Old Guard, there's a scene between Andy and Nile in the cargo plane when they were escaping from Afghanistan. Nile asks Andy how many more of them are there in her army. To which Andy replies "*four*".

Now here's the thing - apart from Andy there are only Nic, Joe and Booker in the team. So who is the fourth person here? Was this just a mistake made by the production while writing the dialogs or was Andy actually privy to the fact that

> Qyunh was alive all along and she is the fourth member.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## There are four in total, including Andy.

This becomes clear by the rest of the dialog.

> - You said there were others. How many?
> - Four.
> - You're an army of four?

When Nile asks how many, despite being ambiguous, she means "how many in total", and Andy responds correctly, they are four, and Nile will be the fifth.

**In other words, no, Andy did not know.**

Comment: That makes sense. I probably did mis-understand Nile's slightly ambiguous question. Although what made me think otherwise was the scene in the old church outside Paris, where the team starts talking about Andy's past. She seemed visibly agitated and uncomfortable. Was it just the pain or something else that was gnawing at her?

Comment: at the end of the movie, Andy comments to Nile that Andy might have lost her immortality as soon as Nile found hers, which would mean that at that moment, there actually were only 4 (excluding Andy). Which leads to another question -- why did it seem that only Nile dreamt of Qyuhn?

Comment: I would say that those comments could qualify as stand-alone questions

Comment: @rosends That cant possibly be true since Andy kills herself in front of Nile to prove she is immortal. And that happens after Nile has her immortality.